# Multiple image uploads cause 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, image, upload

I want to implement multiple sections on my website, where visitors can upload their images to be shown.
I got it to work perfectly in a test folder on the server, where it echoes "File is an image. [file] succesfully uploaded" and the image appears on the server.

However, with the actual implementation of this script into the website (I copied the scripts to a different folder), I get returned: 500 Internal Server error.

Does anyone of you know what could cause this issue?

The HTML form (in /entries.php):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link href="../../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#000000">    
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><p class="text">
            Upload your entry here!:
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP script (in upload.php):

```
<?php
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: check your webserver (probably apache2) log files, it will show you what the 500 internal error is for

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, my webserver is hosted by GoDaddy. I can see log files on who's connecting what page, but no error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `upload_max_filesize` in the php.ini may need to be increased.

```
echo ini_get ("upload_max_filesize");
```

This command will give you the value, then you can go into your php.ini and increase it if not sufficient.

### [httpd.conf configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) for `FcgidMaxRequestLen`  may need to be increased.

In this case you can create a new apache directive in your httpd.conf similar to the following.

FcgidMaxRequestLen *bytes*

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    MaxRequestLen 15728640
</IfModule>
```

### Your hosting company is not allowing PHP access to the directory you have specified for your upload.

Since each hosting company has a different configuration the process may vary. But here is the process for GoDaddy and Plesk.

[Can I use open_basedir on my server running Parallels Plesk Panel?](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1619/can-i-use-open_basedir-on-my-server-running-parallels-plesk-panel)

### If you have an .htaccess in that directory, move it temporarily and try again.

You'll want to move it from the directory where your PHP script resides, and the directory where your files are uploading. If this allows uploads obviously you know there's a rule/directive in the .htaccess causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already made sure the filesize limit is not exceeded, also fileUpload = On

Comment: Concerning your edit: I have no idea how to get to the httpd.conf configuration. My hosting company uses "Plesk" to configure the server, but it seems to be very limited.

Also, I don't see a .htaccess anywhere. I've also checked the permissions, which shouldn't be the problem

Comment: Take a look at this https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1619/can-i-use-open_basedir-on-my-server-running-parallels-plesk-panel